# ¿ Como puedo obtener los datos de un json obtenido de una url?

Tags: java, json

Tengo este código que consume la URL, pero como hago para extraer datos del JSON me entrega, específicamente quiero sacar el *main* y *description* del array *weather*

> ```
> weather": [
>     {
>         "id": 800,
>         "main": "Clear",
>         "description": "cielo claro",
>         "icon": "01d"
>     }
> ]
> ```

Y este es el código que consume la URL:

```
public class a {

  private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("LA URL DE OPENWEATHER");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Descarga esta libreria [JSON-Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813)

[image: La descargas haciendo click en boundle]

La descargas haciendo click en boundle o si estas utilizando maven copia el codigo que se muestra abajo.
Añade la libreria a tu proyecto y utiliza el siguiente código:

```
String cadenaJson = "[{\"id\": 800, \"main\": \"Clear\", \"description\": \"cielo claro\", \"icon\": \"01d\"}]";
// El json claramente es un Array
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(cadenaJson);
JSONObject objetoJson = arr.getJSONObject(0);
// Y ahora podemos acceder
String main = objetoJson.getString("main");
System.out.println(main);
```

El problema estaba en que tu JSON recibido es en realidad un Array por lo cual debes acceder a la posicion primero.

Espero te sirva el ejemplo ;)

Comment: Que aporta esto a lo que pregunta, si al parecer OP ya esta usando esa libreria???

Comment: Huy tienes mucha razon me disculpo y arreglo el ejemplo que puse, te agradezco por hacermelo notar

Comment: Ahora si creo respondo la pregunta correctamente, al parecer no vi bien el codigo anteriormente

Comment: @Israel-ICM como podria reemplazar al cadena string para agregar la url que me trae los datos directos para no tener que utilizar los valores en duro

Comment: [Problema para obtener objeto "uf"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/307565/ayuda-en-como-puedo-extraer-los-objetos-uf-euro-y-dolar-de-este-json-con-java/307621#307621)