# ¿Cómo puedo extraer los objetos uf euro y dólar de este json?

Tags: java, json

Este es el json que me entrega:

```
{

    "version": "1.6.0",
    "autor": "mindicador.cl",
    "fecha": "2019-11-11T13:00:00.000Z",
    "uf": {
        "codigo": "uf",
        "nombre": "Unidad de fomento (UF)",
        "unidad_medida": "Pesos",
        "fecha": "2019-11-11T03:00:00.000Z",
        "valor": 28080.26
    }
```

Quiero que extraer los datos *uf dólar y euro* con java y no encuentro la manera de hacerlo.

He intentado esto y nada

```
URL url = new URL("http://mindicador.cl/api");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

Pero no o logro la manera de extraer los objetos por separado.

Comment: Tienes que crearte una estructura de clases java que tengan esos atributos.
Cuando llames a ese servicio pasándole ese JSON de entrada, si lo has hecho bien, te lo hace automáticamente, 1 objeto de que obtener los datos.

Comment: @EduBw Como seria una ejemplo de eso, lo agrade seria mucho, saludos.

Comment: Te recomiendo usar alguna librería para realizar esas peticiones: Spring tiene [RestTemplate](https://anotherdayanotherbug.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/implementar-un-cliente-rest-con-spring-resttemplate/), pero hay otras opciones como [Jersey JAX-RS](https://www.baeldung.com/jersey-jax-rs-client) .

Comment: Tal vez esto te sirva [(questions/306638) Extraer datos JSON](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306638/como-puedo-obtener-los-datos-de-un-json-obtenido-de-una-url/306651#306651)

Answer (score 2):

Te creas 2 clases java:

```
public class libro { //clase principal
  private String version;
  private String fecha;
  private String autor;
  private Datos uf; // el nombre de las variables se tiene que llamar tal cual el json, el nombre de las clases como las quieras llamar

 // Constructores y getters y setters

}

public class Datos{
  private String codigo;
  private String nombre;
  private String unidad_medida;
  private String fecha;
  private String valor;
// Constructores y getters y setters
}
```

Y en tu controlador o api o llámalo x :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/ejemplo", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public void ejemplo(@RequestBody libro librito) { // automaticamente el java, transformará el json a una clase java si está bien montado
          librito.getUf.getValor(); // lo manejas como un objeto normal.
}
```

Como estás usando una url, imagino que estás haciendo un servicio rest.

En caso contrario con un ObjectMapper podrás transformar de JSON a JAVA siempre y cuando la correspondencia de las clases sean correctas.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.convertValue(tuJson, libro.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Importa la libreria de [(questions/306638) Extraer datos JSON](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306638/como-puedo-obtener-los-datos-de-un-json-obtenido-de-una-url/306651#306651)

Ahora para hacer al get del JSON realiza el siguiente metodo:

```
public static InputStream getHTTPInputStream(URL url) throws Exception
{
    int redirectedCount = 0;
    while( redirectedCount <= 1 )
    {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        httpConn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        httpConn.setReadTimeout(0);
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);

        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        int resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        if( resCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK ){
            return httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
        else if( resCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || resCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM ) {
            String redirectedUrl = httpConn.getHeaderField("Location");
            url = new URL(redirectedUrl);
        }
        else
            throw new MalformedURLException("can not connect to the url [" + url.toString() + "] Code: " + resCode);

        ++redirectedCount;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Ahora para utilizar el metodo haz lo siguiente:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://mindicador.cl/api");

    InputStream inputStream = getHTTPInputStream(url);
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        result.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    String cadenaJson = result.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(cadenaJson);
    JSONObject objUf = obj.getJSONObject("uf");
    System.out.println(objUf.getString("fecha"));

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Stackoverflow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Stackoverflow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Espero eso resuelva tu problema ;)