# ¿Como extraer objetos de api "mi indicador economico" con java?

Tags: java, json

Como puedo extraer los datos de este json que me entrega la api de mi indicador, adjunto json que me devuelve la respuesta de la pagina

```
{

"version": "1.6.0",
"autor": "mindicador.cl",
"fecha": "2019-11-13T19:00:00.000Z",
"uf": {
    "codigo": "uf",
    "nombre": "Unidad de fomento (UF)",
    "unidad_medida": "Pesos",
    "fecha": "2019-11-13T03:00:00.000Z",
    "valor": 28095.18
}
```

he intentado esto

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://mindicador.cl/api");
            logger.debug(json);
```

pero me da el siguiente error

```
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

no se la manera de llegar al objeto "UF"

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente el error que te sale dice que te falta una llave al inicio de la cadena JSON.

Ahora bien cuando ya tengas arreglada esa parte para acceder al objeto uf haz lo siguiente:

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://mindicador.cl/api");
JSONObject objUf = json.getJSONObject("uf"); // Con esto obtienes el objeto uf
// Y ya si quieres acceder por ejemplo a la fecha puedes hacer lo siguiente
System.out.println(objUf.getString("fecha"));
```

Comment: ese es mi problema, no se como arreglar la llave que me falta en el json, por que si bien el json es retornado por la url de la api, si supieras como arreglar agradeceria un monton, saludos

Comment: Bueno para eso tendria que revisar el metodo `readJsonFromUrl()` que utilizas para poder ver el porque se come una llave o podrias probar simplemente concatenando una llave cuando realizas el retorno en tu metodo que me imagino es algo asi `return new JSONObject("{" + json);`

Comment: De todas formas [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/307565/ayuda-en-como-puedo-extraer-los-objetos-uf-euro-y-dolar-de-este-json-con-java/307621#307621) dejo un ejemplo más completo de algo muy similar que ya respondi anteriormente, espero te sirva.

Comment: creo que sirve el metodo, pero ahora me arroja este error "unable to find valid certification path to requested target", de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: El error es usando el metodo del [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/307565/ayuda-en-como-puedo-extraer-los-objetos-uf-euro-y-dolar-de-este-json-con-java/307621#307621)?

Comment: Al debugguear el codigo, y pasar por 
URL url = new URL("http://mindicador.cl/api");
 se cae y la exception es lo que te menciono anteriormente 
"unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Comment: Creo que te falta el `http://` deberia ser `URL url = new URL("http://mindicador.cl/api");` a no ser que solo te confundiste en el comentario ;)

Comment: solo fue que me equivoque al escribir el comentario, pero use "URL url = new URL("http://mindicador.cl/api"); con el http incluido" y nada, me continua dando el error "unable to find valid certification path to requested target",

Comment: mmm la verdad no me pasa, parece ser un error con el certificado, intenta poniendo `https://`

Comment: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1] esa es la excepcion que me da al debugguear, en intento colocando la url como me mencionas pero da de igual manera al error.

Comment: Bueno en ese caso necesitaría ver el contenido del método `readJsonFromUrl()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Toma la respuesta de tu api y pasala a una variable
```

var data = {

```
"version": "1.6.0",
"autor": "mindicador.cl",
"fecha": "2019-11-13T19:00:00.000Z",
"uf": {
    "codigo": "uf",
    "nombre": "Unidad de fomento (UF)",
    "unidad_medida": "Pesos",
    "fecha": "2019-11-13T03:00:00.000Z",
    "valor": 28095.18
}
}

Luego con la consola podrias navegar hasta el objeto y sus atributos de esta forma
console.log("objeto",data.uf);
console.log("atributo de objeto",data.uf.nombre);
```

Comment: Esto que es, una respuesta? porque asi como esta, no se entiende nada...

Comment: ¿En javascript?

Comment: la verdad esque serviria con js, pero estoy trabajando con java(aparte de no dejar nada en claro) tampoco me serviria pq los valores quedarian en bruto

Comment: Hola  Jcastillovnz esto no parece una respuesta, revisa [answer] y edita esta publicación, saludos!