# Como obtener un valor de un json a un String de java?

Tags: java, json

Estoy trabajando en el Request de un  web service soap 
y en uno de sus parámetros tengo mandar unas posiciones en tipo String, el campo se llama **posiciones**

Hay un objeto llamado **Respuesta**  en el cual contiene atributos, y uno de ellos es **respuestaUser**, es de tipo String, el cual contiene las posiciones que debo mandarle a mi request, pero este atributo contiene formato json  de esta manera

```html
respuestaUser = {"tipoSeccion":"Principal", digito1:5, digito2:7}
```

y lo que yo necesito es sacar el valor del **digito1** y el **digito2**, y concatenarlos, osea 57, y ese valor mandarlo al campo **posiciones** para mi request

como puedo hacer para obtener ese valor del atributo **respuestaUser**?
tengo que convertir algo mas a json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrias guiarte por [éste link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306638/como-puedo-obtener-los-datos-de-un-json-obtenido-de-una-url/306651#306651) para descargar la libreria para utilizar `JSON` y allí también encontrarás un ejemplo. Pero de todas formas dejo el código de como seria en tu caso:

```
JSONObject objectJson = new JSONObject("{\"tipoSeccion\":\"Principal\", digito1:5, digito2:7}");
String concat = objectJson.getInt("digito1") + "" + objectJson.getInt("digito2");
System.out.println(concat);
```

Espero te sea de utilidad ;) Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Tres cosas:

1. **Utiliza la libreria org.json.JSONObject** que puedes encontrar [aqui](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20190722/json-20190722.jar) y la doc [aqui](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html).
2. **Si lo que quieres es concatenar** (en lugar de sumar) el valor de los dos dígitos entonces debes convertirlos primero a un String con el método toString().
3. **Si después quieres tratar el resultado de la concatenación como un Integer** entonces debes parsearlo con la función parseInt.

Puede ser algo tan sencillo como lo siguiente:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class jsonexample
{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String respuestaUser = "{tipoSeccion:Principal, digito1:5, digito2:7}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(respuestaUser);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.get("digito1").toString() + jsonObject.get("digito2").toString()));

    }   
}
```

Comment: La pregunta es de Java no de javascript.

Comment: Edito entonces. Gracias.